# Pushing object into an array but object shows empty when making api call

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I declare my array as so:

ListModel contains the following properties:
id, email, value, status

```js
let newArray: ListModel[] = []; 

let newObj = new ListModel();
```

I have a forloop in which i set the data for the newObj and at the end i push the newObj into the newArray like so:

in a forloop i populate the newObj like so:

```
let newArray: ListModel[]=[]; 
for(let j=0; j<rows.length; j++){
    let newObj = new ListModel();
    for(let i = 0; i<result.length: i++){
     newObj.email = result[i].email,
     newObj.value = result[i].value  
    }
    newArray.push(newObj);// here i see newObj contains values
    console.log(newArray);// here i see an empty object pushed into the array.
}
```

In my console, while debugging i can see that newObj has all the values i need  but when i make my api call i see that the pushed object into the newArray all the values are null. As if i pushed an empty object into the array.

```js
api.post('...', newArray).then(response =>{...//code})
```

At this point i can see an object pushed into newArray but the values of the object properties are null

Why are the objects being pushed into the array as empty objects.

Comment: And how exactly are the object properties populated…?

Comment: Please add the `for` loop where are setting the properties of `newObj` and pushing the object to `newArray`

Comment: You need to move `let newObj = new ListModel()` and `newArray.push(newObj)` inside the `for` loop. Also, `foreach(var item in result)` is invalid javascript.

Comment: @adiga thanks for the suggestion.. i updated my code i have two forloops.

Comment: I see there are a few syntax errors. Fix those first so the code will run and see what you can learn.

Comment: If you have a `.then` **and** the `console.log` appears outside of the `then` callback, then indeed you would get this behaviour. Is the code you provided above really reflecting correctly where you do `console.log`?